# Return Text from textbox to stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a function in a webForm that executes a stored procedures. I know the procedure works - I hard coded the parameters for testing. I would not like to allow the user to input the parameter from the winForm.

```
Function code
 <WebMethod(Description:="Retrieve members of a Client List"), SoapHeader("MessageSoapHeader", direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.In)> _
    Public Function GetNextClientListMembers() As DataSet
        Dim RS As SqlDataReader
        RS = objApp.ConnectUser(MessageSoapHeader.UID, MessageSoapHeader.PWD, MessageSoapHeader.Campaign, MessageSoapHeader.Keyword, LocalCommon.apSOAPAdvanced)
        If objApp.ClassErrorsCount > 0 Then
            Dim NX As New Exception

            LLIB.ThrowSOAPException(objApp.Errors(1).Number, NX, objApp.DB, objApp.Errors(1).ErrorType, objApp.Errors(1).Description)
            GetNextClientListMembers = New DataSet
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim GetNext As New SqlCommand("optinPagingNext", objApp.DB)
        GetNext.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        AddSQLCmdParm(GetNext, "@Shortcode", SqlDbType.Int, "", objApp.ShortCode, 0)
        AddSQLCmdParm(GetNext, "@Keyword", SqlDbType.VarChar, "", objApp.Keyword, 0)
        GetNext.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageNumber", goToPage.Text)
        GetNextClientListMembers = LLIB.GetDataSet(GetNext)
        LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetNextClientListMembers.Tables(0).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)
        LLIB.FunctionCount(objApp, "GetNextClientListMembers") 'This must be placed after the close of RS
        GetNextClientListMembers.Tables(0).TableName = "Cell Numbers"
        LLIB.RecordRowTransfer(GetNextClientListMembers.Tables(0).Rows.Count, LLIB.RowTransferDirection.ToClient, objApp)
        objApp.DB.Close()
    End Function
```

The particular line I need help with

```
GetNext.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageNumber", goToPage.Text)
```

I get an error that says the goToPage.Text is not declared.

I have put the textbox on the winform but after that I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the textbox within the same form? If so me.goToPage.Text. If not, then [form name}.goToPage.Text would be my first try.

Comment: I had to place the variable declaration in the function call as well as send it from the originating instance